# How Go compiled file works on different OS or CPU architectures?

Tags: go

Since I have started to learn Golang since yesterday :) I have a question about the compiled file.

Let's assume that I compile my project. It generates an .exec file in /bin folder. 
Now my question is Since the file has been compiled on Mac with Intel based CPU, should it be compiled on other OS and other CPU architectures such as AMD, ARM, etc. if I want to publish it to public?

I guess this should not be problem if I'm using GO lang for my backend since I run it on a server. However, what happens if I publish my .exec file, let's say on AWS, with lots of instances that they are automatically increases/decreases based on load? Does it problem?

**Edit**:

This is nice solution for those how are looking Go cross compiling tool https://github.com/mitchellh/gox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes.  The current implementations of Go produce a native binary, so you will probably need a different one for Linux x86 (32-bit), Linux x64 (64-bit), and Linux ARM.  You will probably need a different one for Mac OS X also.  You should be able to run the 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system as long as any libraries you depend on are available in 32-bit form on that system, so you might be able to skip making a 64-bit executable.

In the future, there may be other implementations of Go that compile for a virtual machine (such as JVM or .NET), in which case you wouldn't need to compile multiple versions for different architectures.  Your question is more about existing Go implementations than the language itself.

I don't know anything about AWS, but I suggest you ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks David for clarification.

Comment: From the Go authors' statements, I don't think it's likely that Go will ever compile to a VM. For AWS, build for a single architecture (say, amd64) and make sure all of your instances use a 64-bit OS. For what it's worth, it sounds like asker is just starting out; in that case, maybe Google App Engine would be a more welcoming environment than an autoscaling AWS setup.